# Conditionally format cells with matching text if a checkbox is checked in Google Sheets

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, gs-conditional-formatting

How can I apply conditional formatting with a custom formula that uses text AND a checkbox as its criteria?

I have two columns of names and I want to be able to toggle highlighting with checkboxes from a third column. So if I check the "Paul" box, all the cells with "Paul" in it will highlight.

Desired result:

[image]

I can achieve the proper highlights without the checkbox if I use the following formula in the Custom Formula box of Conditional Formatting: `=countif(B2,"Paul")`

But I only want to activate this code if `D3=TRUE`

I tried `=IF(D3=TRUE,countif(B2:C11,"Paul"))` Which is a formula that works in a cell (returns the number 8)... but this only seems to highlight one cell (B2) when entered in the Custom Formula box.

I've seen examples of checkboxes toggling formatting on cells or rows, which is where I got the `COUNTIF` code, but nothing I've seen helps with the specific text search.

I'm happy to set up a different formatting rule for each name, unless there was a `HLOOKUP` formula that worked dynamically!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is to lock down the **D3** like this:

```
=COUNTIF(B2,"Paul")*($D$3=TRUE)
```

[image: 0]

---

or you can use `COUNTIFS` like:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2,"Paul",$D$3,TRUE)
```

[image: 0]

---

or use just this:

```
=(B2="Paul")*($D$3=TRUE)
```

[image: 0]

---

or even like this:

```
=IF(($D$3=TRUE)*(COUNTIF(B2,"Paul")),1)
```

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know WHY my original solution didn't work (besides the $ lockdowns)? Are the custom formulas in the conditional formatting box limited to `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: well, as shown on images from answer its not limited to COUNTIF at all. if you want to use IF statement you will need to do it like this:     `=IF(($D$3=TRUE)*(COUNTIF(B2,"Paul")),1)` - eg you need criterions to be boolean not result of something. this way this formula translates as IF(TRUE*TRUE do TRUE(color) which translates as: IF(1*1=1 do color. multiplication is literally the AND function. what you had was: IF(TRUE do result(count) - thats why it did not work

Comment: also keep in mind that everything put in Conditional formatting acts as ArrayFormula unless it's frozen with $. so if you use `=IF($D$3=TRUE,COUNTIF(B2,"Paul"))` on range B2:C then it will freeze D3 reference to be pointing only to specific cell but B2 is not locked down eg. it acts as arrayformula eg. as soon as B2 is evaluated formula shifts on C2 then B3 then C3 and so on. so it kinda jumps on every cell in given range. having B2:C11 (as you had) is confusing for conditional formatting to be evaluated coz it will treat the whole range against criteria eg it will not jump from cell to cell

Comment: Great explanations. Thanks for the fish, then the fishing lesson!